# make jquery animation faster

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

while loading a page i am using a animation,

```
wid=jQuery(window).width()+400;
jQuery('#div').animate({'marginLeft' : '+='+wid+'px'},{queue:false, duration:20000 })
```

div, is being moved to left in 20 sec.

I use this animation for loading page.
when page is loaded `<body onload=myfunction()>` is called.
when myfunction is called (page is loadad completly) i want to my animation faster.

how to change an animation duration while it's animating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably best off interrupting the animation and queuing up a new one with the desired duration.

```
$('#div').stop(true, false).animate(...);
```